# Modify the skeleton of new Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have setup a project skeleton for my Rails apps, and I want to make this skeleton the default project skeleton for newly created apps.

One way is to modify the project template files for Rails (if there are any, which I am not sure). This (if possible) will be over-written each time Rails is updated.

Does anyone have a better idea how to do this?

Comment: You're looking for generators, see: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own [application template](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/rails_application_templates.html).

This can be passed to the `rails new` command:

```
rails new app_name -m your_template
```

Where `your_template` is either a filesystem path or an URL.

To make this your default, create a `~/.railsrc` file and add

```
-m your_template
```